# React refs when parent and child are function components

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have two React components, Parent and Child. Both must be function components. I am trying to change the state of Child from Parent. I believe the best way to do this is using refs, but I haven't been able to get it to work.

I've tried creating a ref in Parent and passing it down to child, but this causes an error. I considered forwardRef() but I'm not sure that will work either.

```
const Parent = () => {
  const ref = React.useRef();

  const closeChild = () => {
    ref.current.setOpen(false);
  };

  return (
    <div>
      <Child ref={ref} onClick={closeChild} />
    </div>
  );
};
```

```
const Child = () => {
  const [open, setOpen] = useState(false);

  return (
    <div>
      {open ? <p>open</p> : <p>closed</p>}
    </div>
  );
};
```

The code as it is now produces this error message:

> react-dom.development.js:506 Warning: Function components cannot be given refs. Attempts to access this ref will fail. Did you mean to use React.forwardRef()?`

Comment: try `onClick={closeChild}` ( no prenthesis)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From the [docs](https://reactjs.org/docs/refs-and-the-dom.html),

> Refs provide a way to access DOM nodes or React elements created in the render method.

`refs` are not meant for changing the `state`.

You actually need `useState` in parent component, and later you can manage it from child component.

```
const Parent = () => {
  const [open, setOpen] = useState(true);

  const toggleChild = () => {
    setOpen(!open)
  };

  return (
    <div>
      <Child onClick={toggleChild} open={open}/>
    </div>
  );
};
```

```
const Child = (props) => {
  return (
    <div>
      {props.open ? <p onClick={props.onClick}>open</p> : <p onClick={props.onClick}>closed</p>}
    </div>
  );
}
```

[Demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-mkhtyw)

Comment: Ahh sorry I had to open in a new window. As a side note the onClicks in `<p onClick={props.onClick}>open</p>` and `<p onClick={props.onClick}>closed</p>` can be changed to `<p>open</p>` and `<p>closed</p>` because the onClick is handled by the parent

Comment: How can parent handle onClick on child component? Parent component just can pass reference to function, we need to explicitly write onClick in child component.

Comment: Sorry you are correct, was having some trouble in your demo where my changes weren't being reflected so thought that it was still working. +1 for causing trouble

Comment: This works, thank you! I was just looking at the problem the wrong way.

Answer (score 5):

Only stateful React components can expose the ref automatically. If using functional component, I think you'll need to use forwardRef for the child component:
e.g.

```
const FancyButton = React.forwardRef((props, ref) => (
  <button ref={ref} className="FancyButton">
    {props.children}
  </button>
));

// You can now get a ref directly to the DOM button:
const ref = React.createRef();
<FancyButton ref={ref}>Click me!</FancyButton>;
```

Answer (score 1):

I don't think you need refs here, you should really try to avoid them.

> avoid using refs for anything that can be done declaratively. They are useful for:
>
> > 1.Managing focus, text selection, or media playback.
> >
> > 2.Triggering imperative animations.
> >
> > 3.Integrating with third-party DOM libraries.

https://reactjs.org/docs/refs-and-the-dom.html

why not just send the value into the child through props?

```
const Parent = () => {
  const [open] = useState(false);

  const toggleChild = () => {
    this.setState(prevState => {open: !prevState.open});
  };

  return (
    <div>
      <Child onClick={toggleChild} open={this.state.open}/>
    </div>
  );
};
```

```
const Child = (props) => {
  return (
    <div>
      {props.open ? <p>open</p> : <p>closed</p>}
    </div>
  );
};
```

EDIT: forgot you were using hooks. This is the way then

```
const [open, setOpen] = useState(false);

  const toggleChild = () => {
    setOpen(!open);
  };

  return (
    <div>
      <Child onClick={toggleChild} open={open}/>
    </div>
  );
```

EDIT 2: @ravibagul91 pointed out that you need to put the onClicks in the children `<p>` elements as well, look at his answer

Comment: Ah. I was just about to respond with something similar. +1!